# Javascript Generalise Function for Multiple Objects (Raphael JS)

Tags: javascript, raphael, pass-by-reference

I'm working with the Raphael JS library and trying to create a hoverIn and hoverOut function that can be applied to any target.

I think the problem is a function of lacking pass-by-reference (I'm very new to JavaScript).

After I create a set of paths and add attributes to view them:

```
Services = rsr.set();

Services.push(
    rsr.path("M698.5,98.617V96.09c0.289,0.256,0.636,0.484,1.04,0.689    c0.403,0.203,0.829,0.375,1.276,0.516c0.445,0.143,0.896,0.25,1.347,0.326c0.45,0.078,0.867,0.113,1.251,0.113    c1.318,0,2.305-0.242,2.955-0.732s0.977-1.193,0.977-2.111c0-0.496-0.106-0.922-0.325-1.291c-0.217-0.365-0.517-0.699-0.898-1.002    c-0.383-0.301-0.836-0.592-1.359-0.865c-0.521-0.275-1.088-0.568-1.689-0.875c-0.64-0.32-1.235-0.648-1.788-0.982    c-0.555-0.33-1.033-0.697-1.442-1.098c-0.408-0.398-0.729-0.854-0.964-1.359c-0.235-0.504-0.351-1.1-0.351-1.781    c0-0.834,0.184-1.561,0.549-2.178c0.366-0.615,0.846-1.125,1.442-1.525c0.596-0.398,1.273-0.697,2.036-0.893    c0.761-0.197,1.537-0.295,2.328-0.295c1.804,0,3.119,0.219,3.943,0.65v2.412c-1.082-0.748-2.468-1.123-4.161-1.123    c-0.468,0-0.938,0.051-1.404,0.148c-0.469,0.098-0.885,0.258-1.251,0.479c-0.367,0.223-0.665,0.504-0.894,0.854    c-0.23,0.35-0.346,0.775-0.346,1.275c0,0.471,0.087,0.873,0.262,1.215c0.174,0.342,0.433,0.65,0.772,0.932    c0.341,0.281,0.754,0.555,1.244,0.818c0.488,0.264,1.052,0.555,1.69,0.865c0.653,0.324,1.275,0.666,1.862,1.021    c0.587,0.357,1.103,0.754,1.546,1.188c0.441,0.432,0.793,0.916,1.054,1.443c0.258,0.525,0.389,1.133,0.389,1.811    c0,0.904-0.178,1.666-0.53,2.293c-0.353,0.625-0.828,1.137-1.43,1.523c-0.599,0.393-1.291,0.676-2.074,0.852    s-1.608,0.264-2.477,0.264c-0.29,0-0.646-0.025-1.071-0.072c-0.427-0.049-0.859-0.117-1.303-0.203    c-0.443-0.09-0.862-0.201-1.258-0.332C699.055,98.926,698.737,98.777,698.5,98.617z"),
    rsr.path("M722.425,93.344h-9.229c0.033,1.457,0.425,2.58,1.175,3.371    c0.747,0.791,1.776,1.188,3.089,1.188c1.473,0,2.825-0.484,4.061-1.457v1.969c-1.148,0.832-2.669,1.25-4.558,1.25    c-1.847,0-3.299-0.596-4.354-1.781c-1.058-1.188-1.583-2.855-1.583-5.01c0-2.035,0.575-3.691,1.729-4.975    c1.152-1.279,2.584-1.922,4.295-1.922c1.712,0,3.035,0.555,3.972,1.66s1.404,2.643,1.404,4.607L722.425,93.344L722.425,93.344z     M720.279,91.57c-0.008-1.211-0.299-2.15-0.875-2.822c-0.574-0.672-1.372-1.01-2.394-1.01c-0.987,0-1.825,0.354-2.515,1.061    c-0.69,0.707-1.114,1.629-1.277,2.771H720.279L720.279,91.57z"))
    ).attr({
    fill: '#010101',
    stroke: '#000000',
    'stroke-width': 0
});
```

I add hover in and hover out events by appending the following:

```
.hover(
    function(){Services.animate({"fill": "#128A8F"}, 500), 
    function(){Services.animate({"fill": "#010101"}, 500));
```

And this works fine.

However, I'm applying this effect to many paths in my script and apply it through hover boxes, so I need to be able to make the hover function more malleable.

I attempted the below to generalise the hover target to a passed object, but it doesn't work probably because JavaScript is pass by value:

```
function menuHoverIn(target){
        target.animate({
            "fill": "#128A8F"
        }, 500);
    };

function menuHoverOut(target){
        target.animate({
            "fill": "#010101"
        }, 500)
    };
```

So how do I make the above functions work as I'd expect them to in JavaScript?  I merely want the passed object to be animated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but I think I see what you're getting at: you just want to be able to pass re-usable hover functions into an element or set.

Before the solution, I have to correct you on one point: JavaScript is NOT a pass-by-value language, at least not all of the time.  JavaScript passes reference types (objects) by reference, and atomic types (string, number, boolean) are passed by value (unless they are wrapped in their associated object types).

Also, before I continue, I'd like to offer some advice about writing better SO questions (that are more likely to be answered).  First, try to boil your problem down to something simple and easy to digest.  In this case, no one cares (or wants to see) your long paths.  You could have replaced those with circles, and you would have had an easier to read question.  Secondly, provide all the information needed to reproduce your problem.  Not everyone is going to know the details involved in setting up a Raphael object, etc.  Preferably, provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (it can be tricky with a library like Raphael which may not have a CDN -- but I was able to find a copy of Raphael on a CDN).  Try to follow JavaScript conventions; it will reduce confusion among people trying to answer your question.  In your case, you call your object `Services`, which is not only opaque to readers of your question, but upper-cased variables in JavaScript are typically reserved for object constructors.

Okay, on to the solution:

If you look at the [documentation for hover](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover), you see that `.hover()` takes two functions, and then two *context objects*.  What this means is that JavaScript is calling the functions with either `call` or `apply`, which sets the context (i.e., the `this` variable) of the functions, as if they were method calls.  So, what you want is something like this:

```
var paper = Raphael( 0, 0, 200, 200 );  // create Raphael surface
// re-usable hover functions:
function menuHoverIn(){
    // note the use of 'this'; we are animating the 'this' object,
    // as if this were a method on an object.  JavaScript is very
    // flexible this way, and this method can (and will) be called
    // as if it were a method of the element you're trying to animate
    this.animate({'fill': '#128A8F'}, 500);
};
function menuHoverOut(){
    this.animate({'fill': '#010101'}, 500);
};

var set = paper.set();   // create Raphael set; renamed from "Services" in OP
    set.push( paper.circle( 50, 50, 25, 25 ) )    // put a circle in the set
    .attr({                          // set attributes of all elements in set
        fill: '#010101',
        stroke: '#000',
        'stroke-width': 0
    })
// provide .hover function for entire set; notice how we pass in set itself
// as the hover in and out context (which will become the 'this' value)
.hover( menuHoverIn, menuHoverOut, set, set );
```

As it turns out, Raphael sets the contexts to the object being operated on by default, so setting the context in this case is actually unnecessary.  This is sufficient:

```
.hover( menuHoverIn, menuHoverOut );
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demonstrating this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FyhDF/).

Comment: Thanks!  Making a JSFiddle account now, and learning more about JavaScript passing.
Contexts makes it work exactly like I wanted to.

Comment: You're welcome, @Kylamus.  Happy coding!  It can be hard making the jump from a Lisp/Clojure background to JS, but I think you'll find JS quite rewarding once you wrap your head around some of its idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
var menuHoverIn = function(target) {
    target.animate({
        "fill": "#128A8F"
    }, 500);
};

var menuHoverOut = function(target) {
    target.animate({
        "fill": "#010101"
    }, 500)
};

something.hover( menuHoverIn, menuHoverOut );
```

Here is two good articles about object "and" functions : http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/guide  and http://jamesallardice.com/explaining-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/

To animate another object :

```
// Function.prototype.bind polyfill
if ( !Function.prototype.bind ) {

  Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {
    if(typeof this !== 'function') // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');

    var slice = [].slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        self = this, 
        nop = function () {}, 
        bound = function () {
          return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} ), 
                              args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );    
        };

    bound.prototype = this.prototype;

    return bound;
  };
}

var menuHoverIn = function(target) {
    this.animate({
        "fill": "#128A8F"
    }, 500);
};

var menuHoverOut = function(target) {
    this.animate({
        "fill": "#010101"
    }, 500)
};

something.hover( menuHoverIn.bind(YourElement), menuHoverOut.bind(YourElement) );
```

Maybe you have to do some adjustment but I have a similar code working with me. Don't forget to replace the element by the one you want animated.

Comment: how would i apply this if i wanted to animate a different target than the one being hovered on?

Comment: Mootools has a function bind. But I don't think it is really supported anymore ... I would suggest jQuery.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud, your initial example has `target` being passed in as an argument, which will not work (that's not how Raphael passes the context into the functions).  You have the correct usage in your second example, using `this`.  @Kylamus, see my answer for an explanation of what's going on here.  Also, IMO, you should prefer jQuery to MooTools -- there's nothing wrong with MooTools per se, but jQuery has won the war, it seems.

Comment: @EthanBrown It's seems the first example works for me ... I will search why because I'm ok with your argument. For the choice between Mootools an jQuery, I suggest the same.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting @PierreFourgeaud; I tried and it didn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hk3kV/1/

Comment: Interesting.... The exact same code unless I didn't name the argument `target`... But even by replacing that, it doesn't work in jsfiddle...

Comment: It may be something with my document setup, but this answer worked for me.  Sadly, coming primarily from a Lisp/Clojure background for functional coding, JavaScript is proving a little confusing.  Just started really using it a couple days ago.  So I've little idea what's going on underneath, to be honest.

Will check out jQuery more thoroughly.  Thanks!